# What's the expected output for this program?

Tags: c

What's the output and why? `folk() && (!folk())` I'm not sure if the code after && should be executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  if(folk() && (!folk())) {
    folk();
  }
  printf("Apple\n");
  fflush(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Was that supposed to be `fork()`?

Comment: What are those `<blink>` things doing there?

Comment: @RayToal HTML tags. A rough copy-and-paste

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and change `folk()` to `fork()` or provide a definition for `folk()` to make this a [mcve].

Comment: Two different calls of the same function may provide different results. This is why the code after the `if(...)` may be executed

Comment: As written, there is no output. The code won't compile, so there is nothing to run. Further, why is this C code tagged C++?

Comment: The output has to be apple. The code never enters the if statement

Comment: @kesarling Not necessarily. As Damien stated: 2 different calls can provide different results.

Comment: Anyways, I wonder why people prefer to use Stack Overflow instead of a debugger for that kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `folk()` returns `false`, the second part of the `if` statement (i.e. `!folk()`) is not executed. If `folk()` returns `true`, then `!folk()` returns `false` if the first execution of `folk()` did not change the behaviour of `folk()`.

So, in those situations, the body of the `if` statement is never executed (the condition always returns `false`).

But, if the first call to `folk()` modifies the behaviour of `folk()`, then the body of the `if` statement might be executed.

Example of the latter:

```
bool folk()
{
    static bool ret = false;
    if (ret) ret = false;
    else ret = true;
    return ret;
}
```

Here, `folk()` first returns `true` and then returns `false`, then again `true` and so on.

Now, with this implementation of `folk()`, let's go back to your example:

```
if(folk() && !folk()) { folk(); }
```

- the first execution of `folk()` returns `true`
- the second execution returns `false`, so `!folk()` returns `true`
- since the condition in the `if` statement now returns `true`, the body gets executed, and the third call to `folk()` returns again `true`

Comment: lol true. I was saying in context that the function is a constexpr. If not, then it will definitely be the way damien said it will be.